# Can you use a pattern in XML Schema attribute names?

Tags: xml, schema

Here's an XML sample:

```
<Search ID="Blah"
        input="Some search"
        line1="first line of result"
        line2="second line of result"
        line3="third line of result"
        />
```

The attributes named line1 to line3 are optional and unbound - a given search element could have line attributes all the way up to line99 or something (realistically never higher than 2 digits).  Is there any way of specifying a pattern of acceptable attribute names in an XML Schema so that I could validate this, without manually specifying all optional attribute names up to whatever I actually use?

Ideally I would like something along the lines of:

```
<xs:attribute name="line[0-9][0-9]" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
```

in the schema definition.

I suspect this is not possible, but all of the searches I do to try and find out for sure end up finding ways of using patterns on the actual values of the attributes, not their names, so if someone could please confirm whether this is possible or not, that would be great.

Comment: In an unrelated query, my account seems to be gone - though I may just have lost it, there doesn't seem to be a login option for a plain StackOverflow login anymore, so I used this other account.  Anyone know where I should ask about this please? Meta perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. If you read the XML specification on [attribute declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAttribute_Declarations), you'll notice that attribute names are of type [NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#NCName), which excludes the `[`and `]`characters.

On another note, it is a very strange use of attributes to convey the result of a query. A much more natural format would be

```
<search id="..." input="...">
    <result>
       <line nr="1">bla bla</line>
       <line nr="2">more bla bla</line>
       ...
       <line nr="99">extra bla</line>
    </result>
</search>
```

Comment: Thanks. I find the XML schema documentation fairly opaque to read through most of the time, but it doesn't really surprise me that this is not possible.  Also thankyou for your suggestion on how my XML could actually be structured instead to allow this! They're actually expected results, and we're doing it this way as it makes them much easier to access via MSTest's data driven framework, but if I do ever put the effort in to convert it to a more sensible structure I will likely use this suggestion.